# Vulnerability in glob-parent : angular-devkit, angular-compiler, eslint - does it compromise prod build?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have vulnerability reported by npm audit in `glob-parent` package.

When I run `npm ls glob-parent` I get this:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.0
| +-- copy-webpack-plugin@9.0.0
| | +-- fast-glob@3.2.6
| | | `-- glob-parent@5.1.2
| | `-- glob-parent@6.0.0 deduped
| `-- webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
|   `-- chokidar@2.1.8
|     `-- glob-parent@3.1.0
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@12.1.1
| `-- chokidar@3.5.2
|   `-- glob-parent@5.1.2
+-- eslint@7.29.0
| `-- glob-parent@5.1.2
`-- glob-parent@6.0.0
```

I read it as this glob-parent is being used in

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular
@angular/compiler-cli
eslint
```

Is my understanding correct?

If yes when my question is - **are these packages used in a prod environment (I mean devkit, compiler, lint - doesnt sound like they are needed after the app is build)?**

Or more simply - **will the glob-parent vulnerability expose my prod system anyhow?**

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.0
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 7.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.0
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli           12.1.1
@angular/language-service       12.1.1
@schematics/angular             12.1.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. While your usage is not the same as someone else's, and there's no definitive way someone else can answer this for you, they can venture a guess:

If you look at each package, you can see if you are using it in a prod environment, in a way that an attacker can expose the vulnerability:

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular -> copy-webpack-plugin -> fast-glob
@angular/compiler-cli -> chokidar
eslint
```

I would think `eslint` is just for your developer environment.

I would also think `build-angular` which is used by the angular-cli is for your developer environment.

It also looks like `compiler-cli` is an Angular internal.

Also -- are these in your `dependencies` or `devDependencies`? [Read this article](https://withblue.ink/2020/06/07/is-this-a-dependency-or-devdependency.html) for background on usage of those sections, but the summary probably rings true for you and most users:

> unless you’re confident that every dependency is in the right place, it might be advisable to treat all security alerts for vulnerabilities in dependencies the same way, regardless of whether they are for a dependency or devDependency.

So if you have a vulnerability, treat it as a production vulnerability, unless you are confident it's strictly for your development process.

Comment: thats the thing - all the above arises from a standard made asp.net core angular project. I didnt add any packages myself. they are in dev and optional dependencies.. so a good point you made. however why are they used in prod build then.. :puzzled:

Comment: @BoppityBop I have created https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22007 because I too am puzzled.